# How to handle windows pop ups using selenium 2.0 (webdriver)?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

`enter code here`Brief : I am currently using selenium 2.0 to automate the testing of an UI.Everything was fine till yesterday till i came across pop ups.I am having to handle windows popups.

The problem : 
I am navigating to page using the following code =>

```
driver.get("http://xxx.xx.x.xxx:zzzz/yyyy/"); 
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("username");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.className("rowClass")).submit();
        driver.findElement(By.name("uploadfile")).click();  //this is the browse button
```

Now the problem arises when i click the browse button.It opens up another windows browse file window.What i need to do is to select a file by navigating to the given path and then select a particular file and i am not able to do the same currently.What could be the suggestion.Some one said it was not possible to do the same using selenium 2.0 and to use autoit instead.if someone knows how to do it please let me know else please suggest a better way to get it done.Thanks and regards.

PS :

//this is mentioned as the solution in http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.htmlbut  did not work in my case

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a "How to upload a file in WebDriver?" question which has been asked [many times](https://www.google.com/search?q=webdriver%20upload%20file) :).

Selenium 2 (WebDriver) Java example:

```
// assuming driver is a healthy WebDriver instance
WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.name("uploadfile"));
fileInput.sendKeys("C:/path/to/file.jpg");
```

The idea is to directly send the absolute path of the file to an element which you would usually click at to get the modal window - that is `<input type='file' />` element (or the `Browse` button as you call it).

Also, the `Alert` interface is just for popup JavaScript dialogs - `alert`, `confirm`, `prompt`.